# Even distributon of edges in bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, pseudocode

I am given a bipartite and directed graph, initially without edges. One set of nodes is called subjects, the other set is called objects. Edges can only be constructed from a subject to an object.
The number of subjects (`numSubj`) and objects (`numObj`) are given, respectively.
Moreover the number of available edges (`numEdges`) is given.

The goal is to distribute edges from subjects to objects evenly. This means all subjects should have a similar number of outgoing edges, analogously all objects should have a similar number of ingoing edges. Each subject and object has to have at least one connected edge.

Please suggest a solution (e.g. in pseudo code)

Comment: What does "similar number" mean? Do you want each out-degree to be exactly the same value k? Do you want each in-degree to be exactly the same value p? Do you want k=p? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's index all the items in each set of nodes form 1 to `numSubj` and from 1 to `numObj`. Let's also assume that `numSubj < numObj` (if this is not true than simply flip the sets, solve and flip them again).

Now calculate the total number of edges which is the `lcm` of these numbers, after than you can conclude the number of outgoing edges by dividing the result by `numObj` (`A`) and find ingoing by dividing by `numSubj` (`B`).

After this calculation for each subject create an edge to the calculated number of subject where the number of ingoing edges, `A`, is less then the second number calculated - `B`.

This process can be done like this:
`i` is connected to `[i * B, i * B + 1, ... , i * (B + 1) - 1 ] mod numObj`

> With `2` and `5`:

```
LCM = 10  
Ingoing = 10 / 5 = 2  
Outgoing = 10 / 2 = 5   
1 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5   
2 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

> With `4` and `8`:

```
LCM = 8  
Ingoing = 8 / 8 = 1   
Outgoing = 8 / 4 = 2   
1 -> 1, 2   
2 -> 3, 4 
3 -> 5, 6  
4 -> 7, 8
```

> With `4` and `6`:

```
LCM = 12 
Ingoing = 12 / 6 = 2   
Outgoing = 12 / 4 = 3   
1 -> 1, 2, 3   
2 -> 4, 5, 6 
3 -> 1, 2, 3  
4 -> 4, 5, 6
```